# Scheduling a task in windows10 using .pyw file

Tags: python, task, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a task 'at system startup' but while pressing run at the 'task scheduler' window it is giving following message:

```
How do you want to open this file?
```

The system is asking to choose a program to run this file having extension .pyw.

Comment: try to make a .cmd file with `C:\Python38-32\pythonw.exe C:\path\to\your\script.py` in it and the execute the cmd file at startup or insert this line directly as startup command

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide the full path to the python interpreter in the program/script box. Now, in the "Add arguments" box add the name of the file you want to run and provide the path to the python file directory in the "start in" box. Take care that you don't accidentally include the python file you want to run in the directory path. Example: If I want to schedule the "sample.py" file located in D:\Python Projects\ then in the "Start in" box I would write "D:\Python Projects" not "D:\Python Projects\sample.py".